# What options do I have in 2023 to sync my React application with the backend with minimum code?

Tags: reactjs, database, synchronization, replication

I need to build a backend + frontend application with three layers:

1. Database layer where I store users, their projects and project-related items
2. API layer with CRUD methods used by frontend application and AI agent.
3. Frontend React + Typescript with some reactive live queries that keep the frontend in sync with DB even when AI changes some data via the API layer.

For example, if the user is working on one of their projects and the AI Agent has changed the project's name, the project name should be updated on the frontend side. Other users should avoid receiving any events about updated data in the project's collection.

I know there are millions of ways of implementing that, but which one requires minimum boilerplate code? I like `liveQuery` implementation from Dexie DB https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/React . However it's a local database for one user, and I need a hosted database for multiple users.

I was looking on Strapi, Directus, MongoDB